stat_compare_means from ggpubr is not producing p-value and throwing warnings in the facet_grid ggplot
I wrote the following R-Code using the following dataset:
Dataset: Dataset
I want to display p-values in the "pre_post_plot" using stat_compare_means. But p-values don't appear in the plot, and instead I am getting 24 warnings listed after the code:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggpubr)

data <- read_csv("test_long.csv")

data <- data %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date),
         Timepoint = ifelse(Date == min(Date), "Pre", "Post"))

data_wide <- data %>%
  select(-Date) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Timepoint, values_from = Value)

data_wide <- data_wide %>%
  mutate(Change = Post - Pre)

pre_post_plot <- data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as_factor(Timepoint), y = Value, color = Group)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(group = interaction(Names, Test)), alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_compare_means(aes(label = paste0("p = ", after_stat(p.format))), method = "t.test", paired = TRUE) + 
  facet_grid(Test ~ Group, scales = "free") +
  theme_par() +
  labs(title = "Pre and Post Intervention Fitness Test Results",
       x = "",
       y = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  grids(linetype = "dashed")

change_plot <- data_wide %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = Change, color = Group)) +
  geom_violin(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, alpha = 0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ Test, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_par() +
  labs(title = "Change in Performance Pre to Post Intervention",
       x = "",
       y = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  grids(linetype = "dashed")

pre_post_plot
change_plot


There were 24 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

warnings()
Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: p.
2: Computation failed in stat_compare_means().
Caused by error:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: p.
4: Computation failed in stat_compare_means().
Caused by error:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
5: Unknown or uninitialised column: p.
6: Computation failed in stat_compare_means().
Caused by error:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
7: Unknown or uninitialised column: p.
8: Computation failed in stat_compare_means().
Caused by error:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
9: Unknown or uninitialised column: p.
10: Computation failed in stat_compare_means().
Caused by error:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
11: Unknown or uninitialised column: p.
12: Computation failed in stat_compare_means().
Caused by error:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
13: Unknown or uninitialised column: p.
14: Computation failed in stat_compare_means().
Caused by error:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
15: Unknown or uninitialised column: p.
16: Computation failed in stat_compare_means().
Caused by error:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
17: Unknown or uninitialised column: p.
18: Computation failed in stat_compare_means().
Caused by error:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
19: Unknown or uninitialised column: p.
20: Computation failed in stat_compare_means().
Caused by error:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
21: Unknown or uninitialised column: p.
22: Computation failed in stat_compare_means().
Caused by error:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
23: Unknown or uninitialised column: p.
24: Computation failed in stat_compare_means().
Caused by error:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default

Current Output without p-values
I am expecting the p-values to appear in the scientific notation in the "pre_post_plot"

The ggpubr package uses the ggsignif package 'under the hood' to plot p-values. If you call geom_signif() directly you can pass in p-values that you calculate manually, e.g.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)

data <- read_csv("~/Downloads/test_long.csv") %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date),
         Timepoint = ifelse(Date == min(Date), "Pre", "Post"))
#> Rows: 336 Columns: 5
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr  (3): Names, Group, Test
#> dbl  (1): Value
#> dttm (1): Date
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

data_wide <- data %>%
  select(-Date) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Timepoint, values_from = Value) %>%
  mutate(Change = Post - Pre)

stats <- data %>%
  group_by(Test, Group) %>%
  t_test(Value ~ Timepoint, paired = TRUE, ref.group = "Pre")

pre_post_plot <- data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as_factor(Timepoint), y = Value, color = Group)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(group = interaction(Names, Test)), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_signif(data = stats, 
              aes(xmin = group1, xmax = group2,
                  annotations = paste("p =", p),
                  y_position = rep(c(50, 18, 36, 2, 4.25, 5.25), each = 2)),
              textsize = 3, inherit.aes = FALSE,
              vjust = -0.5,
              manual = TRUE
  ) + 
  facet_grid(Test ~ Group, scales = "free") +
  theme_par() +
  labs(title = "Pre and Post Intervention Fitness Test Results",
       x = "",
       y = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  grids(linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.55)))

pre_post_plot


Created on 2024-06-12 with reprex v2.1.0
Would this approach solve your problem?

I found the solution by implementing geom_label and pre-calculating the p-values through the following code:
# Load necessary libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)
library(scales)

# Read the data
data <- read_csv("test_long.csv")

# Convert Date column to Date type and create Pre/Post column
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date),
         Timepoint = ifelse(Date == min(Date), "Pre", "Post"))

# Spread the data to have separate columns for Pre and Post values
data_wide <- data %>%
  select(-Date) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Timepoint, values_from = Value)

# Calculate the change in performance
data_wide <- data_wide %>%
  mutate(Change = Post - Pre)

# Perform paired t-tests and get p-values
p_values <- data_wide %>%
  group_by(Test, Group) %>%
  summarise(p_value = t.test(Pre, Post, paired = TRUE)$p.value) %>%
  ungroup()

# Merge p-values back into the data for plotting
data <- data %>%
  left_join(p_values, by = c("Test", "Group"))

# Plot pre and post values for each test and group
pre_post_plot <- data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as_factor(Timepoint), y = Value, color = Group)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(group = interaction(Names, Test)), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_label(data = p_values, aes(x = 1.5, y = Inf, color = NULL, label = (pvalue(p_value, accuracy = 0.001, decimal.mark = ".", prefix = c("p < ", "p = ", "p > ")))), vjust = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = .3)) + 
  facet_grid(Test ~ Group, scales = "free") +
  theme_par() +
  labs(title = "Pre and Post Intervention Fitness Test Results",
       x = "",
       y = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  grids(linetype = "dashed") + 
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.5,"cm"))
  

# Plot change in performance for each test and group
change_plot <- data_wide %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = Change, color = Group)) +
  geom_violin(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, alpha = 0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ Test, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_par() +
  labs(title = "Change in Performance Pre to Post Intervention",
       x = "",
       y = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  grids(linetype = "dashed")

# Print the plots
print(pre_post_plot)

The solution provided earlier using ggsignif() also works.

Glad you solved your problem @Palash_Gupta. You can 'accept' your own answer in this case (re Help Center: Can I answer my own question?
